# Find and Select Dates

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to build a simple macro to find a date and select all the cells that contain this date (I then have another working macro that modifies the selected cells). However I cant get the find and select to work.

At the moment the code is picking up the first "Jul-18" and then it is spitting out  the no match message.

Any help would be much appreciated;

```
Sub FIND()

On Error GoTo nomatch

Cells.FIND(What:=Jul - 18, LookIn:=xlValues).Select

nomatch:
MsgBox ("Not Found")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to adapt it to your needs easily.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
Sub FindAndSelectAll()
    Dim str As String, c As Range, r As Range
    Dim strFind As String
    Dim rSearch As Range

    Set rSearch = ActiveSheet.Cells

    strFind = InputBox("Please enter search string")

    With rSearch
        Set c = .Find(strFind, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            Set r = c
            str = c.Address
            Do
                Set r = Union(r, c)
                ActiveSheet.Range(c.Address).Activate
                Set c = .FindNext(c)

            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> str
        End If
        .Activate
        If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but im not really sure what to do with that, if I run it the whole sheet gets highlighted rather then the 20 odd cells that contain July-18

Comment: Not sure what you mean, it seems to be working fine - see the screenshot.

Comment: I just ran it again and it is working for me now as well thanks.      How hard would it be for me to add a message box into the code to prompt for a search item rather then hard coding in "jul-18"  I can see that being useful in the future?

Comment: Use something like `str = InputBox("Enter search value")' and substitute 'str' for the hard coded value.  Cheers,

Comment: I added str = InputBox("SEARCH FOR"), but doesn't this conflict with str = c.Address?

Comment: That was just a quick example.. please see above, it's tested and works with an input box.  Cheers,