# Formatting Cells within a Selection Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a loop macro that changes a row of dates based on cells I have selected. Is there an easy way to format these cells without complicating the code. My company has policies around keeping Macros as simple as possible.

I have tried the below at the top of the code but this formats the whole sheet, not the relevant cells.

```
cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
cells.NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
```

I can do it via the below but it adds 100 lines to the code

```
cell.Offset(0, 0) = "1-Jul-19"
cell.Offset(0, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
cell.Offset(0, 0).NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
```

Is there a way to do this on one line i.e.

```
cell.Offset(0, 0) = "1-Jul-19".HorizontalAlignment = xlRight.NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Scott

---

```
**Sub CHANGE_MONTH_LOOP()
Dim rngMyRange As range
Dim cell As range
Set rngMyRange = Selection
For Each cell In rngMyRange.Cells
cell.Offset(0, 0) = "1-Jul-19"

cell.Offset(0, 1) = "1-Aug-19"

cell.Offset(0, 2) = "1-Sep-19"

Next cell

End Sub**
```

Comment: Woops, didn't notice the date part. Below will do the formatting and alignment. With the date, what are you doing with it? Is it just for a year? Why not hard codee if it is?

Comment: I have 750 worksheets that contain around 15,000 rows for a budgeting system. Last years Budgets go from July-2018 across to June-2020 (27 cells) I need to change these 27 cells in all relevant lines to July-2019 to June-2021.

What I am trying to do is format only the cells I have modified to make sure they are in the "mmm-yy" format and right aligned. It stuffs up the readability of the sheet if everything is right aligned. 

In terms of your code wont that format the entire sheet in that format? (which is what I am trying to avoid).

Comment: no, it only formats row 1 in worksheet Sheet1. As I understand you want to loop through ALL worksheets within the workbook and make sure the format of row1 is "mmm-yy"?

Comment: If the below answer does what you want it to can you please ensure you mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER FROM ANONYMOUS BELOW

```
cell.Offset(0, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight : cell.Offset(0,1).NumberFormat = "mm-yy" :  cell.Offset(0, 0) = "1-Jul-19"
```

Comment: Ok.... sad that you boss thinks less lines = more simple... anyway, if you are happy with your code, just put `:` like the following `cell.Offset(0, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight : cell.Offset(0, 0).NumberFormat = "mmm-yy" :  cell.Offset(0, 0) = "1-Jul-19"` Should work fine in one line

Comment: Less lines is more simple... You just need to understand how to write the less lines ;)

Comment: That's pretty close thanks O.Pal, I was trying avoid having to write the cell.Offset(0, 0) x3 but at least its on one line

is there likely to be a way to do that with the cell.Offset(0, 0) only once or am I dreaming / boss dreaming?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()


    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim irow As Long
    Dim jrow As Long
    Dim StartCol As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long



    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws.Select
            LastRow = ws.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            Set StartDate = Cells.Find(What:="Jul-17", After:=ws.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues _
                        , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
            StartCol = StartDate.Column
            StartRow = StartDate.Row

                For irow = StartRow To LastRow
                    Set Rng = ws.Range(Cells(irow, StartCol), Cells(irow, StartCol + 11))
                        For Each Cell In Rng
                            Cell.Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, Cell)
                        Next Cell

                    Rng.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                    Rng.NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"

                    irow = irow + 2
                Next irow

                For jrow = StartRow To LastRow
                    Set Rng = ws.Range(Cells(jrow, StartCol + 12), Cells(jrow, StartCol + 12))
                        For Each Cell In Rng
                            Cell.Value = "FY19 Total"
                        Next Cell
                    jrow = jrow + 2
                Next jrow
        End With
    Next ws


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to limit the formatting to the cells I have modified using the offset function. The rest of the sheet needs to stay as is. See my pic below.

Comment: @Scottyp There is no difference if you format the style of the dates. Since you are changing each date, the code ensure the same format is used throughout

Comment: This is for a budgeting worksheet so under each date is a dollar value for a respective cost line (or general ledger code for the accountants). At the moment the above is formatting the dollars as days.

Comment: What cell is the first date in?

Comment: Dates usually start in column 3, but in some cases 4 or 5 also.

Comment: That info would have been helpful in the original question. Please ensure you post up all relevant info. Yes this can be done. Please review my revised answer above.

Comment: yeah sorry, I should have put that in. Thanks

Comment: @Scottyp Can you please mark as answered. I hate to go to the trouble and effort and not be rewarded. Cheers!

Comment: I got error 91 when I tried to run it. So what is the code actually doing searching for July-17, then adding a year to the dates and searching for then looping?

Comment: It's searching for the first "Jul-17" in the file. Then going right for each month in the FY and adding 1 year. Then goes down 4 lines and does it again till the bottom, then goes to next sheet and continues the process. I noticed the pic is actually "18" update the code and it'll work. Still debug if it doesnt

Comment: The date entries are not consist, i.e. some are four lines down some are 2, some are 5 depending on how many stores, but if I use this code to find the cells then I could probably adapt it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53291272/find-and-select-dates

Comment: Yes you can do that.. I think I've given you some good tools to use and you have some research and understanding. Seeing as the original question was answered lets mark as answered. And if you can't get this new code to work with the search, post up  another question and we can review

Answer (score 0):

Back again, so if in @alowflyingpig and your boss' world less lines necessarily means more simple please see below a code that does exactly what your "full code" does... but in less lines...

```
Sub DATE_MONTHLY_LOOP()
Dim cell As Range, i As Integer
For Each cell In Selection.Cells: For i = 0 To 11: With cell.Offset(0, i): .Value = DateAdd("m", 1 + i, 43617): .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight: .NumberFormat = "mmm-yy": End With: Next i:    With cell.Offset(0, 12): .Value = "FY20 TOTAL": .ColumnWidth = 11.3: .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight: .NumberFormat = "mmm-yy": End With: Next cell
End Sub
```